# regex to remove parentheses and / (forward slash) form a string

Tags: javascript

I want to remove parentheses and forward slash or backslash `()/\` from the string.

For example... **`Nort()h / (America)`** should be as **`North America`**

few other cases also.

1. North////()America => North America
2. (North America) => North America
3. ((((()()()()(()()No(())))))))rth///////(()))()((()///\\\\\\America///////' => North America
   etc..

Comment: "Nort()h / (America)".replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");

Comment: In your solution, there is the problem. In case North/////America it's returing NorthAmerica. 
expected is North America.

Comment: no it's working fine for me

Comment: no rahul it's not working. if input is North/////America it returns NorthAmerica. It should return North America
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use *regex* `replace`

```
"Nort()h / (America)".replace( /[()\\\/]/g, "" ) //outputs North  America
```

**Explanation**

- `[()\\\/]` is a char set of `()\/` with both backward and forward slash escaped.

Also if you want **multiple consecutive spaces to be replaced with single space** then add

```
var input = "Nort()h / (America)";
var output = input.replace( /[()\\\/]/g, "" ).replace( /\s+/, " " ); //North America
```

**Edit**

Though your logic is unclear, you can try the following

```
var output = input.replace( /\/{2,}/g, " " ) //replace consecutive / with space
                  .replace( /\\/g, " " )  //replace consecutive \ with space
                  .replace( /[()\\\/]/g, "" )
                  .replace( /\s+/, " " );
```

Comment: North/////America it's returning NorthAmerica. Should return North America.

Comment: But you never mentioned in your question that `/` should be replaced by a *space*. Share the exact logic of replacement!

Comment: I mentioned the expected result North America. I understand scenario may be different but the result should be same.

Comment: Didn't get you. Are you saying - regardless of what the input is, output should always be *North America*? As I have mentioned before, you need to share the exact logic of replacement rather than just the expected output.

Comment: sorry, I have updated the title. 
yes output should be North America.

Comment: Sorry, it is still unclear as to why `/////` should be replaced by a space? what is the logic behind that?

Comment: that is a requirement.

Comment: your second solution also not working. if the input is North/////America than it's returning NorthAmerica.

Comment: thanks for your solution. Sorry for being unclear.
Your solution work as expected. 

But I have one concern, is it possible to make it clear and abstract. Is there any other way optimize this solution.

Comment: @kamalsoni It is possible if you can share the exact logic of replacement. At this moment, I am not sure what your logic of replacement is.

Comment: one more thing if there only one slash like 'North/America' than its return 'NorthAmerica'. It should return 'North America'.

Comment: @kamalsoni So `No/rth America` should return `No rth America` as well? As i have mentioned earlier, without your concise logic it is impossible to meet these recurring demands.

Comment: yes if there is No/rth America it should return No rth America.